# ASP.NET Core Authorize Redirection to wrong URL

Tags: redirect, routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to run a web application with the following route mapped:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "default",
                "WoL/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
```

If the user is not authenticated and tries to access a action having the AuthorizeAttribute, the user should be redirected to the default login URL (as seen above). But the user gets redirected to "/Account/Login" instead of "/WoL/Account/Login". How can I redirect the user to "/WoL/Account/Login", if the user is not authenticated? I have configured the following Cookie Authentication:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/WoL/Account/Login"),
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });
```

Comment: Did you try to set the `CookiePath` to `WoL`? More info in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie

Comment: Do you add `app.UseCookieAuthentication()` before the `app.UseMvc()`?

Comment: Could you post `Configure` method(all of code)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer of @Dmitry is not working anymore in ASP.NET Core 3.1. Based on the documentation that you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-full-identity-ui-source), you have to add the following code to the ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
   .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
   {
       options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
       options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
       options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
       options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
       options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
     });
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me (in `Startup.ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>(options => 
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/Admin/Account/Login");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `options.ForwardChallenge = "oidc";` to AddCookie options config